# English statements translation into first order logic statements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I was given the english statement: *If someone can be stabbed, then someone will kill him for sure* 
I'm a newbie in AI, and struggling with simple statements like this one. For example, I'm having even a trouble with naming verbs (can be stabbed => stab(x,y) or should it be stabbed(x,y), or canBeStabbed(x,y)?).

My statement for now looks like that:
ExEy stab(x,y) => kill(y,x) 
Is that correct? Or am I missing something?
 Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Can be stabbed" should take only one argument. You should also say how exactly you define function $kill$. Either way, your current statement doesn't seem correct - depending on how exactly you define your verbs, ir probably means something like "Someone will killed be for sure by someone who can stab them,"

Comment: I think it is useful to rewrite the initial statement as: "For every person X who can be stabbed, there is a person Y who will kill him."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $CanBeStabbed(x)$ mean that $x$ can be stabbed.

Let $WillKillForSure(x,y)$ mean that $x$ will kill $y$ for sure.

Of course you can use other, simpler names.

Then "Someone will kill $y$ for sure" is denoted by $$\exists x\; WillKillForSure(x,y)$$

The statement "If $y$ can be stabbed, then someone will kill $y$ for sure" will therefore be
$$ CanBeStabbed(y) \Rightarrow \big(\exists x\; WillKillForSure(x,y)\big)$$

The English sattement implies that it is supposed to be true for anyone that can be stabbed, that is
$$ \forall y \Big(CanBeStabbed(y) \Rightarrow \big(\exists x\; WillKillForSure(x,y)\big)\Big)$$

That is enough, but if you insist on using two-argument function for stabbing, you can also define $CanStab(x,y)$ to mean that $x$ can stab $y$. Then you can replace $CanBeStabbed(y)$ by $$ \exists x\; CanStab(x,y)$$
Then the formula would be
$$ \forall y \Big(\big( \exists x\; CanStab(x,y)\big) \Rightarrow \big(\exists x\; WillKillForSure(x,y)\big)\Big)$$
It needs to be stressed that it's different than
$$ \forall y \exists x \Big( CanStab(x,y) \Rightarrow WillKillForSure(x,y)\Big)$$
The first allows that the $x$ that can stab is totally different than the $x$ that will kill; in the second the $x$ that will kill must be a one that can stab.

Comment: In my opinion using a two-argument function for stabbing only complicates the matter. A person X can be potentially stabbed by A or B, or even A and B together, and yet end up being killed (for example: poisoned) by C.

Comment: @M.Wind I agree, there's no good reason to introduce another variable (one who stabs) to the formula. That's why I used one-argument function $CanBeStabbed$. But OP for some reason used a two-argument function for stabbing, so I wanted to show how it could be done with such a function.

Comment: Okay. I think the current version of your answer is fine and I have upvoted it.